# App store connect: App Icon becomes white after upload

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I recently added a new app in itunesconnect, but it suddenly shows **"White" / empty icon** after uploading.
I did not encounter any error during upload.

What could be missing/wrong?

[image: Itunesconnect]

### Testflight Screenshot

[image]

### Things I tried - but still not working:

1. Upload new build - with incremental value
2. Delete all icons in assets, then clean, and re-add icons
3. Delete app in appstore then re-create and upload

I uploaded several apps before but never encountered this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that your appIcon isn't transparent and it's added in your Assets.xcassets -> AppIcon
and make sure you put all images sizes.

Comment: but in my case, it was an apple issue. I didn't have to do anything, so i'm thinking something's wrong with apple at the moment. it got fixed, without me doing anything XD